# Length of a Dissertation Summary for a Postdoc job

Tags: application, job-search, abstract

For a job application I am currently putting together, they request a document of **Dissertation Summary and Other Recent Scholarly Endeavors** where I need to, of course, "Summarize your dissertation and other recent scholarly endeavors."

The application page says this is to be a maximum length of 3 pages (excluding references). However, much of what I am finding online says that dissertation summaries should be pretty brief.

What is the typical length of a dissertation summary?

Comment: In my uni we would call this a research statement. It is common to most job ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does typical matter? You have three pages. You may need it or not.

Don't say more than you need to, but give an explanation that the readers can relate to.

My dissertation, which was very involved and quite long could be described (to an expert) in a couple of paragraphs - and they would have been impressed. But other topics would take more explanation than mine did in mathematics.

But, as they imply you may have more to say about other recent scholarly matters - work in progress, for example.